# C - PlaySound() not finding file when passing location as char[]

Tags: c, winapi, playsound

I'm trying to play certain `.wav` files based on an `int` value.  Currently my program makes `.wav` files fine, and I can play them manually.  I'm storing the location of the `.wav` files in a `char[]` member under a structure called `sInt`:

```
extern struct sInt {
    int value;
    enum Color color;
    char fileName[250];
};
```

So the frequency of the `.wav` file is just a constant multiplied by the `value` member in `sInt`.  I currently have an array of struct `sInt` called `arr` and I loop through the array calling all `.wav` files like this:

```
PlaySound(arr[j].fileName, NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
printf("%s \n", arr[j].fileName);
```

But all I hear is the default beep and not the `.wav` file.

I manually went to the `.wav` file to make sure there is sound in the file and there is.

I added the `printf` statement to see how I'm storing the files names and I get this output.

```
D:\Documents - Data Drive\waveFiles\freq2.wav
```

Along with the other file locations, but there all the same except the number at the end. So I copied this `printf` output to my code as this:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("D:\\Documents - Data Drive\\waveFiles\\freq2.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

And it works perfectly.

I don't see why it wouldn't work when I call `arr[j].fileName`.

I'm not sure if maybe I should be passing the location of the file name in a different manner, but I have about 1000 `.wav` files that I need to call freely, so I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing this.  Any help would be appreciated thank you in advanced.

---------EDIT----------

Here is when I assign the wav data to the `.wav` file, this is inside a function where an int `i` is passed:

```
char fileName[250] = "D:\\Documents - Data Drive\\waveFiles\\";
char helpMe[50];
//Generate new file name for specified i;
sprintf_s(helpMe, 32, "freq%d.wav", i);

printf("helpMe = %s \n", helpMe);
//Add new file name to location string
strcat_s(fileName, 200, helpMe);
printf("FileName = %s \n", fileName);
//write wave to wavefile
waveToFile(&mySound, fileName);
array[i].help = i;
printf("done \n");

//free up mem from wav
waveDestroy(&mySound);

//add fileName to sInt fileName
strcpy_s(array[i].fileName, 250, fileName);

printf("FIlename in sInt = %s \n", array[i].fileName);
```

Here is the code where I actually create the `.wav` file when I call `wavToFile()`:

```
void waveToFile(struct Wave* wave, const char* filename) {

    // First make sure all numbers are little endian
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.chunkSize));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.subChunk1Size));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(short int), (void*)&(wave->header.audioFormat));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(short int), (void*)&(wave->header.numChannels));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.sampleRate));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.byteRate));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(short int), (void*)&(wave->header.blockAlign));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(short int), (void*)&(wave->header.bitsPerSample));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.subChunk2Size));

    // Open the file, write header, write data
    FILE *file;
    fopen_s(&file, filename, "wb");
    fwrite(&(wave->header), sizeof(struct WaveHeader), 1, file);
    fwrite((void*)(wave->data), sizeof(char), wave->size, file);
    fclose(file);

    // Convert back to system endian-ness
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.chunkSize));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.subChunk1Size));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(short int), (void*)&(wave->header.audioFormat));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(short int), (void*)&(wave->header.numChannels));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.sampleRate));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.byteRate));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(short int), (void*)&(wave->header.blockAlign));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(short int), (void*)&(wave->header.bitsPerSample));
    toLittleEndian(sizeof(int), (void*)&(wave->header.subChunk2Size));
}
```

I know for sure the `.wav` files are being created since I can go to that folder directly and manually open the files and play the sound.

----------EDIT 2--------

So I changed the `printf` statement after the `PlaySound()` call to help see what is being passed to `PlaySound()` when I use `arr[i].fileName`:

```
PlaySound(array[j].fileName, NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
printf("\"%s\"< \n", array[j].fileName);
```

And here is the EXACT output:

```
"D:\Documents - Data Drive\waveFiles\freq2.wav"<
"D:\Documents - Data Drive\waveFiles\freq3.wav"<
"D:\Documents - Data Drive\waveFiles\freq4.wav"<
```

What I would like to restate is if I copy this exact output into `PlaySound()` like this:

```
PlaySound(TEXT("D:\\Documents - Data Drive\\waveFiles\\freq2.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
```

The `.wav` file gets played.  So I'm not sure if when passing the `char[]` to `PlaySound()` it is somehow modifying the string differently than how it's outputted as a string to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Answer thanks to @pstrjds. `PlaySoundW` needs a `wchar*` array passed not a `char*` passed.

So here are the edits I did:

```
extern struct sInt {
    int value;
    enum Color color;

    wchar_t fileName[250];
    int help;
};
```

And when I copy the path of the file to `fileName` I changed the line:

```
strcpy_s(array[i].fileName, sizeof(array[i].fileName), fileName);
```

to

```
swprintf(array[i].fileName, sizeof(array[i].fileName), L"%hs", fileName);
```

to convert from char* to wchar_t*.

Thank you everyone who helped out!

Comment: The second parameter of `swprintf()` is a **character count**, not a **byte count**. `sizeof()` returns a **byte count**. You are opening yourself up to a potential buffer overflow. Use `sizeof(array[i].fileName)/sizeof(array[i].fileName[0])` instead, or `_countof(array[i].fileName)`.